# Prove the following identity for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Prove this:

for any positive integer $a,b,c$,

$F_{a+b+c+3}=F_{a+2}(F_{b+2}F_{c+1}+F_{b+1}F_c)+F_{a+1}(F_{b+1}F_{c+1}+F_bF_c)$

Is there any way other than induction to prove this?

Comment: Do you have to use induction?

Comment: @DanielY No, I want to find a non-inductive proof.

Comment: Binet's formula is one way to go, then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider matrix formula from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form).  Let  $M=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\ 1 & 0}$. Then $M^{a+1}M^{b+1}M^{c+1}=M^{a+b+c+3}$.  However, we can express all of these matrices in terms of the Fibonacci numbers.  Compare both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the formula $F_{a+b} = F_{a+1} F_b + F_a F_{b-1}$?  You might apply that twice (plus some simplification).